# Reading from InputStream to byte[] throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, sockets, networking, inputstream

I obviously don't know where is the problem!, First I ask the client to send me the Length of the `byte[]` he is going to send, then I read for its length like this.

```
int i = 323292; // length of incoming Byte[]
byte[] b = new byte[i]; 
int readBytes=inputStream.read(b,0,b.length);
```

But It always kept reading readBytes less than i. And I am sure that the client sends the whole `byte[]`.

I tried to put it inside a loop, to read till my total number of read bytes is i, but I always get IndexOutOfBoundsException after the second Iteration! here is the code

```
boolean flag = true;
int i = 323292;
int threshold = 0;
byte[] b = new byte[i];
int read = 0;
while (flag) {
    if (threshold < i) {
        System.out.println(threshold);
        try {
            read = inputStreamFromClient.read(b, threshold, b.length);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        threshold = threshold + read;
    } else {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

AnyIdeas?

Comment: You should really use one of the Commons IO packages to save yourself some coding time and unnecessary complexity: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: You don't need third party software for this simple task. See `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
read = inputStreamFromClient.read(b, threshold, b.length);
```

should be:

```
read = inputStreamFromClient.read(b, threshold, b.length - threshold);
```

Comment: And `threshold` would normally be called `offset`. See the API documentation.